# querySelectorAll not firing on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that activates 'showBorder' when a size is selected. works fine on desktop and iPhone but doesn't fire on iPad. is anyone familiar with this issue? it seems strange its fine on iphone but ipad. please see all of my script below:

```js
function applyRecommendedSleeveLength(selectedVal) {
if(selectedVal !== undefined){
var recommendedVal = map[selectedVal.trim()];
        var sleevSwatches = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="attribute__swatch--length-"] div');
        sleevSwatches.forEach(function(swatch, i) {         
        swatch.classList.remove('showBorder');
        });
        var recommendedLi = document.querySelector('[class*="attribute__swatch--length-'+recommendedVal+'"] div');
        recommendedLi.classList.add('showBorder');
        
}
}
```

Comment: Please give all of your code

Comment: @YasharAliabasi please see full code above

Comment: That's alot of code, I'm sure all of it is not related, please try to make it as mininal as possible still demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I think your code is for Node.js and serverside and not for jquery/javascript in client side.am I right? @Olivbelle

Comment: @Esko please see above